# CORS problem while fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

```
// Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY_OR_BEARER_TOKEN' with your actual API key or Bearer token
const apiKeyOrToken = "...";

// Define the base URL of your API
const baseUrl = "https://api.clashroyale.com/v1";

// Define the specific endpoint you want to access
const endpoint = "/players/%2389GU9VUQJ";

// Construct the full API endpoint URL by combining the base URL and endpoint
const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}${endpoint}`;

// Make a GET request to the API with Bearer token authorization
fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: "GET", // Use the appropriate HTTP method (GET, POST, etc.) based on the API documentation
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKeyOrToken}`,
            // Add any other headers as needed
        },
    })
    .then((response) => response.json()) // Parse the JSON response
    .then((data) => {
        // Select the HTML element where you want to display the data
        const dataContainer = document.getElementById("data-container");

        // Create HTML content based on the data
        const htmlContent = `
      <h2>Data from the API</h2>
      <p>${data.name}</p>`;

        // Set the HTML content of the element
        dataContainer.innerHTML = htmlContent;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Please help me fix this:

```
{reason: 'badRequest', message: 'Origin not allowed'}message: "Origin not allowed"reason: "badRequest"[[Prototype]]: Object
(anonymous) @ app.js:25
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ app.js:24
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ app.js:22
app.js:43 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at app.js:37:16
```

I want to display the name of a certain player in the DOM. Problem: CORS. I installed Chrome extension but it is not enough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: does `api.clashroyale.com` allow cross origin requests from a browser?

Answer (score -2):

Normaly to make a request to a different domaine `api.clashroyale.com`, you need to specify `mode: 'cors'` in the fetch function.

```js
fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKeyOrToken}`,
    },
    mode: "cors" // for cross origin request
})
```

But also, in some API account configuration, we need to set all URL origin we will use. Try to look in the doc if `mode: "cors"` doesn't work

Comment: `'cors'` mode is activated by default for cross-origin requests.